# Spring jdbc template connection closed exception while reading clob object

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons, spring-jdbc

I have 5k+ characters to read from each row in oracle DB as CLOB for a select list query . After executing the query using springjdbc the below exception is thrown while trying to convert the CLOB object to String.

```
    public List<MasterData> findByRqstId(int rqstId) {

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM MASTER_DATA WHERE REQUEST_ID = ?";

            List<MasterData> masterDataList = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(sql,
                    ParameterizedBeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(MasterData.class), rqstId);

            return masterDataList;
        }



    Caller Code



    masterDataList = masterDataDao.findByRqstId(rqstId);
            String outputResponse=null;

            if (masterDataList != null && masterDataList.size() > 0) {

                for (MasterData mData : masterDataList) {
                    Clob clob = mData.getOutputResponse();
                    InputStream in = clob.getAsciiStream();
                        StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
                        IOUtils.copy(in, w);
                        String clobAsString = w.toString();
                    outputResponse = clob.toString();

                }

            }
```

I am able to get the clob object. But when I try converting the object to string using the above code , I am getting connection closed exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Close Connection
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getDBAccess(CLOB.java:1421)
    at oracle.sql.CLOB.getAsciiStream(CLOB.java:352)
```

In my knowledge the since the clob object is bigger in size the cache is unable to hold the data for the next operation. The following properties are making no difference.

```
    <property name="connectionProperties" value="defaultRowPrefetch=1000" />

    <property name="connectionProperties" value="defaultLobPrefetchSize=500000" />
```

Comment: The problem is that by the time you access the clob, the connection that produced it is already closed. You should do this in the mapper you pass to the JDBC template. Side note: are you sure you need to use `getAsciiStream` and not `getCharacterStream`?

Answer (score 1):

I am able to retrieve the clob object by convering it as String datatype .Internally I guess Spring takes care of the conversion but its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the exception is that when you are accessing the blob/clob the connection is already closed.

A solution could be:

1. Set the data in Dao itself and return the VO
2. Initiate the transaction through transaction manager (the caller
   must be a transaction manager).